How to know Solaris ipsec keys for ike in pkcs12 format?
I want to convert Solaris ipsec ike keys in a format suitable for Libreswan.
With the command ikecert I export the public key
ikecert certdb -e 0 > public.pem 

and private key
ikecert certlocal -e 0 > public.pem 

Now with openssl I try to convert in pkcs12 format and..
openssl pkcs12 -export -in chiavepubblica.pem -inkey chiaveprivata.pem -out YourName.p12

return this error
4274747236:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

someone know a way to export it or convert in suitable format for libreswan?
Thanks

The ikecert man page says on the certlocal option (emphasis mine):

When specified with the certlocal subcommand, this option extracts a private key from the IKE local ID database. The key data are written to standard output. The slot specifies which private key to extract. Private keys are only extracted in binary/ber format.

So the private key will not be in PEM format, but in a binary format.
Try:
ikecert certdb -e 0 > public.pem
ikecert certlocal -e 0 > private.der
openssl rsa -inform DER -in private.der -outform PEM -out private.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in public.pem -inkey private.pem -out ConvertedIpsecKey.p12
rm private.der private.pem     # don't leave secrets lying around.


Works really fine, only I had to change this line ikecert certlocal -e -f pkcs8 0 > solaris10.private.der
